# How to make parent postgresql in codeigniter

Tags: postgresql, codeigniter

Help me. I want a result to parent->child

```
WITH RECURSIVE subordinates AS (SELECT id,title, parent,level 
    FROM mst.locations UNION SELECT l.id,l.title,l.parent,l.level 
    FROM mst.locations l INNER JOIN subordinates son s.id = l.parent) SELECT * 
    FROM subordinates;
```

How I can take a child per parent?

Comment: Please mark your SQL code on `code tag`

Comment: Please clarify information about your `tables`, `sample data`, `Postgres version`.